# Invalidating cache at request end Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-data

I'm looking at adding a small amount of caching in my application's data layer. Goal:

I have some logic that goes 10-15 methods deep. These methods might require access to collections from the database on every step. Right now, I query for the collection during method1's call and in some cases end up passing the collection around 5-6 calls deep just to avoid querying for it again.

In order to solve this problem, I thought I could cache the query's result and instead of passing the collection around just query for it again and again knowing that I will receive the same response instantly without going to the database. Also, in order to avoid any deprecated objects, my cache invalidation strategy would be to invalidate after every http request ends emulating the act of passing around a collection I queried at the start of the request.

I'm using `SpringData` to access the database and am thinking of using spring's caching annotations to cache repository result data. I checked the docs and it needs a Cache implementation to work (e.g `EHCache` or similar). Looking at their invalidation strategies and I don't seem to be able find anything related to request based invalidation.

Is it possible to do this? Is this a good solution to my problem? Note that I'm using `MongoDB` as a database.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you don't need cache, because your cache duration is the request time. So you just need to put the result in a request scope bean http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

And after just code as Object Oriented, put the collection of method1 in a property of the bean (the request scoped bean) and access it in other method. If it is used in others classes use spring injection.